# Network device problem - Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: networking, 13.04, services

My Ubuntu suddenly doesn't seem to have a wifi adapter..or any network adapater actually. I noticed this after i tried to connect to my office LAN and changed set the LAN settings.

When i open 'Network Connections' i get a message saying something like 'The device is not compatible with this service'

I've also just noticed another problem ..which i think will be better presented after this.

So there it is...any ideas friends?

Answer (score 1):

You have first to try another driver from `jockey`, 
if it does not work then you can use `ndisgtk`if you have your wireless driver for windows this program will create a driver for linux starting from Windows driver,
 
if it does not work you can see [this](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices) for detecting you wireless card then download the driver from [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download)

or finally if those does not work try this
 `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
 or this 
`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` in the command line